Lilypond - Error in timing
I have a piece containing 4 voices: trebleOne, trebleTwo, and bassOne and bassTwo, with the following MWE codes (thanks to this post, the grace note issue was solved, but the timing issue remains):
\version "2.24.2"
\language "english"

global = {
  \key e \major
  \time 4/4
  \tempo  4 = 60
}

trebleVoiceOne = \relative c'{
\global
\clef treble
\voiceOne
b'8 b16 cs~cs8 d~  d cs16 b~b8 gs16 (gs
\time 3/4 a8 fs) r2
\time 4/4 \acciaccatura fs8 gs8\p fs <cs' cs'>4\f <b b'> <d d'> \bar "||"
}

trebleVoiceTwo = \relative c'{
\global
\clef treble
\voiceTwo
<d fs>4 s4 f2  
s1
\grace s8 s1
}

bassVoiceOne = \relative c'{
\global
\clef bass
 <gs, gs'>4 <gs' ds' fs> <cs, gs' b>2
\time 3/4 R1 * 3/4
\time 4/4 \grace s8 r4 <cs, cs'> <b b'> <d d'> 
}

bassVoiceTwo = \relative c'{
\global
\clef bass
s1
s1
\grace s8 s1
}

\score {
  \new PianoStaff  \with {
    instrumentName = "Piano"
  } <<
    \new Staff  \with {
     %\consists "Span_arpeggio_engraver"
      midiInstrument = "acoustic grand"
    } <<
      \new Voice \trebleVoiceOne
       \new Voice \trebleVoiceTwo
    
    >>
    \new Staff   \with {
      midiInstrument = "acoustic grand"
    }  <<
       \bassVoiceOne
      \bassVoiceTwo
      >>
  >>

} 

And the result is this:

So my question is, it seems there is clearly something wrong with my time as illustrated by the empty spaces after the double bar. It is quite strange to me that if I run these 3 bars in each and every voice independently, it ends well but once I have them joined, the time is messed up. Any comments on correcting the time?
Thank you very much.

How is the lower treble voice missing a quarter note at Beat 2 of Bar 1, without even a rest to compensate?

The spacer rests for the trebleVoiceTwo and bassVoiceTwo in the second measure need to be scaled to fit into 3/4. Change some of the s1’s to s2.’s.

Similarly, that full measure rest in bassVoiceOne has been scaled: R1 * 3/4, but you can write this (perhaps more simply) as R2..

@ElementsInSpace Thank you so much, that was smooth! :)
